# How To F2FS Filesystem Encryption?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, f2fs

I read that the f2fs format is good for SSD storage so I formatted one of my drives with it. I also read in some kernel notes that encryption was added for it but there's no documentation to speak of. I typically prefer whole disk encryption. I'm not sure if that's possible for f2fs.

I'm wondering if anyone knows any steps in which I might be able to encrypt an f2fs drive. I know it's done on Android for their full drive encryption (I'm running Ubuntu). Is LUKS filesystem agnostic? I don't think so. Any encryption would be good.

No docs == no good.

Here's a reference of kernel updates: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1506.3/00598.html

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not sure because he says "I know about eCryptFS, LUKES and encfs" and I don't know what the kernel updates apply or how  to go about learning to use them, whether it's per-file/dir encryption, full-disk or both. There's just nothing to reference that I can find.

Comment: I suppose if the answer that was given about LUKS means I can use LUKS with my F2FS drive then that will do but I want to know about the kernel updates.

Comment: I do not know why someone down voted this question. It might not have the best phrasing, but is no duplicate to the other, as the other wants to encrypt only parts of the file system and this question is about encrypting the whole FS. It is also not related to LUKS, because as far as I can tell, f2fs has a seperate encryption method which is not related to LUKS. What I do not know, is if this method of f2fs can be applied to a whole filesystem and not just to all parts.

Answer (score 5):

Out of [f2fscrypt](https://www.mankier.com/8/f2fscrypt) man page:

`# mkfs.f2fs -O encrypt /dev/sdxx`
`# mount /dev/sdxx /encrypted/`
`# mkdir /encrypted/dir`

First create the key in the keyring use an simple salt
(or generate a random salt).
Then use it to set the policy for the directory to be encrypted.

`# f2fscrypt add_key -S 0x1234`
`Enter passphrase (echo disabled):`
`Added key with descriptor [28e21cc0c4393da1]`

`# f2fscrypt set_policy 28e21cc0c4393da1 /encrypted/dir`
`Key with descriptor [28e21cc0c4393da1] applied to /encrypted/dir.`

`# touch /encrypted/dir/test.txt`
`# ls -l /encrypted/dir/`
`-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar  5 21:41 test.txt`

After each reboot, the same command can be used set the key for
decryption of the directory and its descendants.

`# ls -l /encrypted/dir/`
`-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar  5 21:41 zbx7tsUEMLzh+AUVMkQcnB`

`# f2fscrypt get_policy /encrypted/dir/`
`/encrypted/dir/: 28e21cc0c4393da1`

`# f2fscrypt add_key -S 0x1234`
`Enter passphrase (echo disabled):`
`Added key with descriptor [28e21cc0c4393da1]`

`# ls -l /encrypted/dir/`
`-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar  5 21:41 test.txt`

Show process keyrings.

`# keyctl show`
`Session Keyring`
`084022412 --alswrv      0     0  keyring: _ses`
`204615789 --alswrv      0 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.0`
`529474961 --alsw-v      0     0   \_ logon: f2fs:28e21cc0c4393da1`

Figuring out how to implement this in boottime

Answer (score -2):

LUKS *is* filesystem agnostic. It works at a lower level than the filesystem. LUKS is how Android does full disk encryption.

Comment: Right but I'm not just asking about LUKS. I saw in linux kernel update that F2FS encryption has been added in some fashion. Anything secure would be great but there are no docs on how.

Comment: So I should just be able to follow the LUKS procedure on an F2FS formatted drive?

Comment: LUKS would apparently render F2FS useless, hence why we need to use file/dir encryption now provided [link](http://superuser.com/questions/729551/linux-luks-and-choice-of-filesystem)

Comment: @xendi You can use LUKS with F2FS. You create the LUKS container first and then the filesystem, just like with any other filesystem. LUKS does work with TRIM and it doesn't “make F2FS useless”. The point of encryption on top of F2FS is if you want per-file encryption, i.e. if you don't want full disk encryption.

Comment: We want to keep TRIM features :(

Comment: Doesn't LUKS pass TRIM through?

Comment: Apparently you can but it degrades security. I thought there was an encryption scheme for F2FS specifically and that's what I really wanted.

Comment: @Gilles, Your reputation preceedes you (literally, in this case), but if you'd be interested, I just started a bounty for a related question at Superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/729551/linux-luks-and-choice-of-filesystem